# AngularJS - Use function as filter inside controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

If I have a filter defined

```
app.filter('filterName', function() {
    return function(var) {
        // Some filter stuff
    }
}
```

I can invoke it on controller doing `$filter('filterName')($scope.someObj);`.

But, here is my question, if I have a function that use as a filter

```
$scope.myFilterFunction = function() {
    return true;
}
```

In my HTML

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items | filter:myFilterFunction">{{item}}</p>
```

How can I use this function filter in the controller (I have tested with $filter but throws an error).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you already implement the custom filter `filterName`, why not use it?

**Try**

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items | filterName">{{item}}</p>
```

---

**Updated**

You just missing the parentheses.

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items | filter:myFilterFunction()">{{item}}</p>
```

Comment: My question is how ti use the filter function inside controller.

Comment: There is no way you can achieve that, if you wish to use $scope.myFilterFunction as the filter in HTML as pipe, you need to implement it same like the filterName.

Comment: Well, that is a answer. Then I have to implement as a custom filter instead a function. Ok, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it can be use in controller as you described. You are just missing the parantheses, updated the answer.

Comment: Man, you are using the filter inside the view, HTML. I am saying about using it inside the controller code (for example, take an array an apply the filter inside a function)

Answer (score 0):

Inject $filter in the controller and use it with your filter name.

```
controller.$inject = ['$filter'];

function controller($filter){
// code here    
  $filter('filterName')(arg1,arg2);
//
}
```